# Open an encrypted file with specific user

Tags: encryption

I need to decrypt a file without saving the decrypted data of the file on the computer. I will explain.
Let's assume I have an encrypted file on my file server (the encryption's algorithm is irrelevant)
Now when the file is triggered by an open event I call the following code:

```
public void FileOpenning()
{
    // Only "Foo" can decrypt and see/change the content of the file
    if (Environement.CurrentUser == "Foo")
    {
        // Display the encrypted file to the user
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing, the user can't open the file.
    }
}
```

Now, I want to show the user the file without actually decrypt the file itself, if I will do so, anyone who has an access to the file server will be able to watch the file, since it is already decrypted (and as you can see, only "Foo" can decrypt and see the content of the file)
Another option I thought about is saving the decrypted data in a temporary file, but it is still unsecure and it will be complicated to change the content of the file again and save it since I will need to encrypt the file again..
Any suggestions of how can I handle it?

Comment: Well, the way you've written this, it sounds like the server itself has the key. That means that anyone with enough access can read the file any time they want. You need to clarify your threat model.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really matter how the encryption/decryption works, I'm talking more about the concept of how only a specific user will be able to see the encrypted content

Comment: You want a general solution, independent of encryption algorithm. I understand that. That doesn't mean key management is irrelevant. You said "anyone who has an access to the file server will be able to watch the file, since it is already decrypted". This implies an attacker who can ignore file permissions. Such an attacker can also read the key that the server used to decrypt the file. Thus, it doesn't matter whether you decrypt the file in memory or on disk; you're still hosed either way. You see?

Comment: Ok, now I understand now what you meant. I will try to explain again.
We still didn't plan the whole architecture, but I guess that the server that will hold the key will be another server.I guess we will install this server to be with top-protections.
I am talking about an access to a file share such as netapp, so if an attacker has an access to the file share it doesn't mean he has an access to the key.
I'm afraid about two issues:
1. A person who will get an permission to a file that he doesn't have the key to open it.
2. An attacker that will be able to monitor the file share.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean that the encrypted file (EF) is somewhere on a
cloud server (CS), and you have a secure, dedicated server (SS), not in
the cloud, that holds the key. So:

1. User foo establishes an SSL/TLS connection to SS and authenticates
   themselves with a password or whatever.
2. User foo requests the file.
3. SS makes sure that user foo is authorized to access that file.
4. SS retrieves EF from CS and decrypts it locally. (It doesn't matter
   whether SS decrypts EF in memory or stores the plaintext on SS's
   disk, since we have to assume SS is secure.)
5. SS transmits the plaintext to user foo. The SSL/TLS connection
   ensures that no one can listen in.

Of course, the plaintext ends up on the machine that user foo is using.
That's unavoidable. There may be ways to keep it in RAM only, and not on
the disk, depending on how big it is and how it's being viewed.

Is that what you mean?